# PHP_Incomplete_Class on Symfony getLastAuthenticationError()

Tags: php, symfony

Following this tutorial:
https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/security.html
I was able to setup a login controller with an User Entity like this:

```
#[Route('/login', name: 'login')]
public function index(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils): Response
{
    // get the login error if there is one
    $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

    // last username entered by the user
    $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

    var_dump($error);
    //die();
    return $this->render('login/index.html.twig', [
        'controller_name' => 'LoginController',
        'last_username'   => $lastUsername,
        'error'           => $error,
    ]);
}
```

Everything works but the call to getLastAuthenticationError() for some reasons returns a PHP Incomplete class which generates errors in TWIG

```
object(__PHP_Incomplete_Class)#1 (6) { ["__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name"]=> string(65) "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\BadCredentialsException" ["0"]=> object(__PHP_Incomplete_Class)#2 (4) { ["__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name"]=> string(74) "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken" ["0"]=> string(5) "kölk" ["1"]=> string(4) "main" ["2"]=> array(5) { [0]=> string(6) "klköl" [1]=> bool(false) [2]=> NULL [3]=> array(0) { } [4]=> array(0) { } } } ["1"]=> int(0) ["2"]=> string(16) "Bad credentials." ["3"]=> string(116) "/var/www/html/.../Authentication/Provider/UserAuthenticationProvider.php" ["4"]=> int(73) }
 Symfony E
```

My symfony version is 5.4 and my php is 8.1
I use it in an nginx environment
Would could be wrong ?

My security yaml looks like this

```
security:
enable_authenticator_manager: true
providers:
    # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
    app_user_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\User
            property: username
firewalls:
    main:
        provider: app_user_provider
        pattern: ^/
        lazy: true
        logout:
            path: logout
        form_login:
            # 'login' is the name of the route in the LoginController.php
            login_path: login
            check_path: login

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
    - { path: ^/?, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/?, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

Comment: "BadCredentialsException" dont use `var_dump()` use `dump()`  and try again

Comment: I get the same result.The problem is __PHP_Incomplete_class .. something with the session and serialization of the object passed between the sessions. But it should be something inside symfony.